# What are some good Linux distros for current development use?

Tags: linux, development-environment

Main concern is that when I try CentOS I see that GCC is out of date. Is there a distro that is geared towards developers?

Comment: You don't need the latest GCC in order to write code.  In fact, the bleeding-edge versions are more likely to have issues.  Better to have a stable distro with tested and stable tools, than to look for the latest version with all new shiny stuff.

Comment: Well I'm not looking for bleeding edge, if by that you mean unstable builds. I am looking however for versions that have major speedups in terms of compilation time. I'm also looking to have versions of the compiler that are as up to date as possible on c++0x features.

Comment: What kind of development? Do you use tools like make, autoconf/libtool, valgrind?

Comment: Personally, i wouldn't worry but so much about C++0x til it actually becomes a standard.  Every compiler can have its own take on the stuff that isn't set in stone yet -- so what you write based on the latest draft could become useless by the time C++0x is finalized.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, develop on what you'll deploy on. If you need to run your code on e.g. RHEL, it might cost you a lot of time if you develop on a recent Ubuntu/Fedora machine (older Python version, different version of libpcap, initscripts not working, just to mention a few time-wasters when we went that route and were oblivious to what we needed to deploy on)

If that isn't your concern, Fedora, Ubuntu, Debian - or really, any recent distro with a fairly big community will do fine.

(also, gcc on Centos5 isn't out of date, it works quite well - and if absolutly needed you can compile/install the current gcc release from source)

Comment: I was advised not to try to update CentOS' version of GCC. Maybe that was bad advice.

Comment: Install a new version in parallell (e.g. somewhere under /opt). You should indeed not update/replace the stock gcc in CentOS.

Comment: What is the rational for not replacing stock gcc on CentOS?

Comment: @fpmurphy: The stuff that's built for a given release of a given distro sometimes assumes certain things about the compiler that was used to build it, or assumes that other apps (and kernels!) on that system were compiled the same way.  There are times that changing the compiler changes how the source code gets interpreted, or just barely changes how stuff gets linked, and can cause very strange and subtle bugs to appear.

Comment: The compiler included with the distro is pretty much guaranteed to work fine with all the important stuff in that distro.  Earlier or later versions, not so much.  So the distro's compiler should be the one used if any system stuff ever needs to be rebuilt.  Unless of course you want to ditch RPM and manage half the distro by hand...which i wouldn't.